# How can I handle memory allocation errors in the following code?

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
const unsigned long long TABLE_SIZE = (1ULL << 34);

class HashMap {
private:
      HashEntry** table;
public:
      HashMap() {
            table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                  table[i] = NULL;
      }
};
```

The above code on compilation throws the following exception: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc" whereas the code below throws no errors or warnings and compiles properly.

```
const unsigned long long TABLE_SIZE = 65536;

class HashMap {
private:
      HashEntry** table;
public:
      HashMap() {
            table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                  table[i] = NULL;
      }
};
```

I believe the "bad_alloc" exception is being thrown because the system ran out of memory. I would like to know how to get around this problem to get this code to work.

Comment: `1ULL << 34` is 16 *billion*. Multiply that by `4` or `8` (the size of pointers on 32 and 64 bit systems respectively) and you have the number of bytes needed. Do you have that amount of memory? In a *single contiguous block*?

Comment: As for possible way to solve your problem, the first and most obvious would be to use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of implementing your own hash-map.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I was expecting an answer more in terms of being able to free up existing unused memory.

Comment: @Akshaya freeing memory isn't the issue. And it certainly won't solve your problem. You're asking for 64, or 128 (depending on your pointer size) **gigabytes** of contiguous memory. I have to ask. What algorithm on earth requires an *initial* bucket count in a hash table of 17179869184 slots? Fyi, if your pointer size if 4 bytes due to a 32bit platform, this absolutely cannot work, as you will be limited to at most 4GB of addressable memory (and far less than that on platforms like Windows). I suspect an XY problem, to be honest.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `TABLE_SIZE` fits in `int`, so `for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)` is likely undefined behavior.

Comment: If you want to implement your own HashTable, do something like existing classes does. Initialize with something lower like 16 in Java and keep growing whenever it gets filled.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of a pointer, your first block of code is requesting 128 gigabytes of contiguous memory (I am assuming 64-bit addresses, because you cannot even address that many bytes in a 32-bit address space). This is a certain way to run your system out of memory even before you start allocating `HashEntry` objects themselves!

Fortunately, hash tables commonly require a lot fewer buckets than that: hash code gets translated to the actual range of valid bucket indexes with modulo `%` operator, and then a collision resolution algorithm is used to deal with multiple hash values being "mapped" to the same bucket. This approach lets you "fold" a large space of possible hash values onto a much smaller space of valid hash indexes.